# Firestore: primitive vs object

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was starting to use Firebase Firestore database for the first time and was wondering which would be better to use, object or primitives when using variables such as int, long, or bool.

I've tried to look at similar questions or official documents but nothing answers this particular question.

The Firestore introduction link is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). In [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) it shows an example of a custom object being added that has primitive variables. Finally, [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) shows the supported data types which include object variables as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the decision you're trying to make.  Firestore objects are just containers for other data types.  Could you edit the question to more clearly state the specific decision you're trying to make, and how that models the data for your app?

Comment: I just meant when creating custom objects that I will be storing in Firestore, would it make a difference if I made the object's states as objects or primitives such as Boolean or bool and what is the difference if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both primitive and object versions of data types will map to the exact same Firestore types.  The decision of which one to use is entirely up to you, but the general convention is to use primitive types unless you want their values to be null at some point.